# JSP Expression Language not work in Apache Tiles

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, apache-tiles

Hello i try to migrate my `Spring MVC` application to use `Apache Tiles 3.0.5` as template engine.
But when i access my web application, my EL's value not work.
My value comes from `ModelMap model`.

```
...
model.addAttribute("billings", billingService.getAllBillings());
...
```

Here is my spring configuration.

```
...
<context:component-scan base-package="com.fanjavaid"></context:component-scan>
    <mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>

    <mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"></mvc:resources>
    <bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
                <value>/WEB-INF/views/**/views.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="tilesViewConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass">
            <value>org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView</value>
        </property>
        <property name="order" value="0"></property>
    </bean>
...
```

And below is my tiles definition configuration.

```
...
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="indexpage" extends="base.definition">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Index"></put-attribute>
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/views/includes/header.jsp"></put-attribute>
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp"></put-attribute>
    </definition>
    <definition name="listpage" extends="base.definition">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="List"></put-attribute>
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/views/includes/header.jsp"></put-attribute>
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/list.jsp"></put-attribute>
    </definition>
    <definition name="showpage" extends="base.definition">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Show"></put-attribute>
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/views/includes/header.jsp"></put-attribute>
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/show.jsp"></put-attribute>
    </definition>
</tiles-definitions>    
...
```

I already try to put `isElIgnored` but it not works.
May be i miss some configurations?

Thank you.

Comment: try replacing your tilesViewConfigurer bean with  <bean id="viewResolverTiles"
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesViewResolver">
  <property name="order" value="1" />
 </bean>

Comment: @ObiWan-PallavJha stilll doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was having a generated web.xml as well as the AppInitizlier that extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer (to replace web.xml). When I removed the web.xml, the el expressions began to work.